Duplicate problem after using append() - how to rebuild innerHTML by js or jquery?
Could anybody help me with following problem of my code,please?


<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" CONTENT="pl" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>         
<div id="main"><div id="title"><div id="content"></div></div></div>
    
<script>       
function init() 
    {                
    var maindata = "Background";    
    var titledata =  "Some title";        
    var contentdata =  "Some content";
    
    init_layout();
    update_layout();
        
    function update_layout()
        {            
        // HOW TO UPDATE DATA??? - MEANING: 
        // DELETE, INIT NEW DATA WITH SAVE HTML TREE STRUCTURE?            
                    
        // IF I TRY REFRESH DATA LIKE THIS BELOW, 
        // innerHTML will refresh, 
        // BUT also will contain duplicate in any element 
        // where append() was used
        jQuery('#content').html(contentdata);        
        jQuery('#title').append(titledata);
        jQuery('#main').append(maindata);        
        }
    
    function init_layout()
        {                                                         
        jQuery('#content').html(contentdata);        
        jQuery('#title').append(titledata);
        jQuery('#main').append(maindata);        
        }                                                     
    }                   
jQuery(document).ready(init);
</script></body></html>



There are three html nested div elements. Each of them should have only single data, NOT DUPLICATE as it is...

Ok "professionals" from this "amazing" portal... ;) X)
Problem solved :) BTW - many "thanks" i could count on help here (no results after two days, and no chance to use secrets words like "empty()" - which is jquery function i need to tag this post for better visibility - sic!). Of course, maybe some day be more easy to get some "points of experience" here X) X) X) LOL.
Sorry to the real begginers of webdeveleping, but perhaps you find more help in other portal then this (w3sshols etc)
May the false be with you "professionals" of jquery and javascript! XD

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
